# Is it possible to do the same without using load()?

Tags: lua

Is it possible to achieve the same result without using the load function here?

```
function f1(arg)
    print(arg)
end

function f2(arg)
    print(arg)
end

functionTable = {}
stringTable = {
"f1",
"f2"    
}

for i,v in pairs(stringTable)do
    load("functionTable." .. v .. "=" ..v)()
end

functionTable['f1']("arg")
```

Comment: `functionTable[v]=_G[v]` or `functionTable[v]=_ENV[v]`

Comment: Thank you so much this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
functionTable[v]=_G[v]
-- or
functionTable[v]=_ENV[v]
```